# Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automated-tests, codeception

When I run an acceptance test on a remote linux server in Jenkins, the job fails

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException] Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'


Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I run the selenium server with the command

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./Codeception/chromedriver -jar ./Codeception/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -port 17570 &
```

and run test

./composer.phar install

- php codecept.phar run tests/acceptance/Jenkins_test_Cept.php --debug

Chrome version: 108.0.5359.124

Console log

```
+ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./Codeception/chromedriver -jar ./Codeception/selenium-

server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -port 17570
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/***
+ cd Codeception/Brand_Analytics
+ ./composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Generating autoload files
+ php codecept.phar run tests/acceptance/Jenkins_test_Cept.php --debug
```

How I can solve this problem? I'm new in Jenkins and have no idea what to do

Comment: you can try to give the executable path of the chrome driver in Jenkins under `Global Tool Configuration`

Comment: @Sourav, Could you tell me in which field I need to specify the path to chromedriver?

Comment: You can try to install the chrome driver plugin in Jenkins. https://plugins.jenkins.io/chromedriver/

Comment: Sorry for such a long answer. I installed the chromedriver plugin but I don't see it in the Global Tool Configuration. I restarted the server, but it didn't help either. What could be the problem and are there any alternative solutions?